# Possible to create custom chrome executable?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, memory-limit

I am currently using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) for monitoring data, but what I have noticed is that it uses a lot of memory, and often times crashes chrome. My question is, is it possible I can create my own custom chrome executable with an increased memory limit? I'm not even quite sure where I'd begin with doing such a thing or if it is possible. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance! Here is the current memory usage + some. [image: Memory Usage]

Comment: What's the relation b/w Grafana and chrome here? If the Grafana uses more memory shouldn't you have to decrease chrome usage?

Comment: @Biswapriyo When I build queries using Grafana, chrome more than often will crash due to their not being enough memory (Or at least that is my understanding?) So I was just thinking of possible solutions, and thought maybe increasing's chrome cache memory could fix the issue? I'm not sure as I am not knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: Well, there are [many command line options](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that you can try. Also `chrome://flags` may help.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Any command line option you have in mind in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Grafana as a long-running display, perhaps with auto-refresh?

Chrome (and possibly other browsers) appear to just accumulate data updates from Grafana - and memory usage climbs accordingly. Users report problems like this with varying intensity, from [v2.6](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3794) up to recent [6.x](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/15731) releases.

Instead of writing a new executable, you could periodically refresh the Grafana tab so Chrome releases memory. Using the built-in Playlist feature should accomplish this (since v3.0, it does a page reload [[ref](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3794#issuecomment-209461469)]).